# Wordpress + Cloudflare SSL redirects to apache root?

Tags: wordpress, apache, https, cloudflare

We recently deployed our new website and when trying to use it over SSL with cloudflare, it redirects to the Apache root dir?

I generated origin TLS certificates and downloaded those from cloudflare for the domain and then configured the virtual host to use SSL:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>


       ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /home/domain/public_html
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/cert/domain.com.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/cert/domain.com.key
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I've tried cloudflares flexible, full and strict SSL setting.

But for some reason, it still goes to the default dir of apache?

I just cannot grasp why.

Comment: Do you have any page rules set at Cloudflare?

Comment: @DocRoot 

Nope, just regular A record DNS to domain name to the webserver and using cloudflares CDN / Http proxy.

Comment: Is Cloudflare handling the SSL?   If so, it may be proxying your site via HTTP.  Check to make sure that port 80 requests are also going to that directory.

Comment: Yeah it's a HTTP proxy, and I've tried forcing HTTPS via cloudflare, no dice.